# Can you use the OPENTBS_EDIT_ENTITY to change Word settings?

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I use the OPENTBS_EDIT_ENTITY 'word/settings.xml' to change the updateFields setting currently in Word and that has always worked great. Could I also use that for settings like turning view table gridlines on/off, setting print layout view, and show/hide hidden characters (like the paragraph marks, spaces, etc)? If so, how do you find the right format of different settings?

Comment: It seems that View mode and Showing hidden characters are settings of the Ms Word application, they are hold by the document.

Comment: You mean they are NOT held by the document in the settings.xml file so I wouldn't be able to specify then, is that right?

Comment: That’s correct. They are not held by any part of the DOCX at all.